# Heap Sort vs Insertion Sort JMH benchmark: why my insertion impl. takes less time?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort, heapsort

I've implemented both Insertion sort and Heap sort. In theory, Heap sort has nlogn time complexity and insertion has n^2. Why, then it takes my Insertion implementation about x6 times faster to sort a 100,000 long array?

I used JMH for benchmarking the average time of each sort algorithm.
Here's my benchmark code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

public class MyBenchmark {

// setup the benchmark - create a new array for each iteration
    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class MyState {
        int[] array = null;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void doSetup() {
            array = createArray(100000, 0, 100);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void insertionSort(MyState state) {
        int[] array = state.array;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            int element = array[i];
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (element < array[j]) {
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = element;
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void heapSort(MyState state) {
        int[] array = state.array;
        sort(array, array.length);
    }

    public static void sort(int[] arr, int size) {

        for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
            maxHeapify(size, arr);
            int temp = arr[0];
            arr[0] = arr[size - 1];
            arr[size - 1] = temp;
            size--;
        }
    }

    private static void maxHeapify(int size, int[] arr) {
        int nonLeafs = size / 2;
        for (int i = nonLeafs; i > 0; i--) {
            int arrayPos = heapToArrayPos(i), leftChild = heapToArrayPos(leftChild(i)),
                    rightChild = heapToArrayPos(rightChild(i));
            if (rightChild < size) {
                if (arr[rightChild] < arr[leftChild]) {
                    if (arr[arrayPos] < arr[leftChild]) {
                        switchWithLeftChild(arrayPos, arr);
                    }
                } else if (arr[arrayPos] < arr[rightChild]) {
                    switchWithRightChild(arrayPos, arr);
                }
            } else if (arr[arrayPos] < arr[leftChild]) {
                switchWithLeftChild(arrayPos, arr);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int heapToArrayPos(int heap) {
        return heap - 1;
    }

    private static int rightChild(int pos) {
        return pos * 2 + 1;
    }

    private static int leftChild(int pos) {
        return pos * 2;
    }

    private static void switchWithRightChild(int pos, int[] arr) {
        int father = arr[pos];
        int childPos = heapToArrayPos(rightChild(pos + 1)), child = arr[childPos];
        arr[childPos] = father;
        arr[pos] = child;
    }

    private static void switchWithLeftChild(int pos, int[] arr) {
        int father = arr[pos];
        int childPos = heapToArrayPos(leftChild(pos + 1)), child = arr[childPos];
        arr[childPos] = father;
        arr[pos] = child;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(MyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName()).forks(1).build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    public static int[] createArray(int length, int minValue, int maxValue) {
        return IntStream.generate(() -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minValue, maxValue)).limit(length)
                .toArray();
    }

    public static int[] createArray(int length) {
        return createArray(length, 0, 10);
    }

    public static int[] createArray(int minValue, int maxValue) {
        return createArray(10, minValue, maxValue);

    }
}
```

And here is the benchmarking output:

> JMH 1.12 (released 51 days ago)
>   VM version: JDK 1.8.0_65, VM 25.65-b01
>   VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java.exe
>   VM options: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xbootclasspath:C:\Program 
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\tools.jar
>   Warmup: 20 iterations, 1 s each
>   Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
>   Timeout: 10 min per iteration
>   Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
>   Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
>   Benchmark: org.sample.MyBenchmark.heapSort
>
> Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:01:20
>   Fork: 1 of 1
>   Warmup Iteration   1: 17.651 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   2: 16.004 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   3: 14.640 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   4: 14.699 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   5: 14.836 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   6: 14.900 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   7: 14.758 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   8: 15.084 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   9: 15.652 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  10: 15.121 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  11: 15.315 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  12: 15.299 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  13: 15.234 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  14: 14.822 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  15: 15.078 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  16: 15.565 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  17: 15.509 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  18: 15.189 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  19: 14.748 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  20: 14.902 s/op
>   Iteration   1: 14.888 s/op
>   Iteration   2: 15.381 s/op
>   Iteration   3: 16.099 s/op
>   Iteration   4: 15.536 s/op
>   Iteration   5: 15.635 s/op
>   Iteration   6: 16.446 s/op
>   Iteration   7: 16.034 s/op
>   Iteration   8: 15.828 s/op
>   Iteration   9: 15.666 s/op
>   Iteration  10: 16.071 s/op
>   Iteration  11: 15.962 s/op
>   Iteration  12: 15.777 s/op
>   Iteration  13: 15.757 s/op
>   Iteration  14: 15.424 s/op
>   Iteration  15: 15.449 s/op
>   Iteration  16: 15.920 s/op
>   Iteration  17: 14.609 s/op
>   Iteration  18: 14.651 s/op
>   Iteration  19: 14.661 s/op
>   Iteration  20: 14.607 s/op
>
> Result "heapSort":
>     15.520 ±(99.9%) 0.486 s/op [Average]   (min, avg, max) = (14.607, 15.520, 16.446), stdev = 0.560   CI (99.9%): [15.034, 16.006] (assumes normal distribution)
>
> JMH 1.12 (released 51 days ago)
>   VM version: JDK 1.8.0_65, VM 25.65-b01
>   VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java.exe
>   VM options: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xbootclasspath:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\tools.jar
>   Warmup: 20 iterations, 1 s each
>   Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
>   Timeout: 10 min per iteration
>   Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
>   Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
>   Benchmark: org.sample.MyBenchmark.insertionSort
>
> Run progress: 50.00% complete, ETA 00:10:15
>   Fork: 1 of 1
>   Warmup Iteration   1: 1.726 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   2: 1.636 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   3: 1.968 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   4: 1.970 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   5: 1.961 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   6: 1.966 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   7: 1.962 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   8: 1.961 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration   9: 1.959 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  10: 1.965 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  11: 1.966 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  12: 1.970 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  13: 1.964 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  14: 1.952 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  15: 1.955 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  16: 1.956 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  17: 1.972 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  18: 1.966 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  19: 1.954 s/op
>   Warmup Iteration  20: 1.956 s/op
>   Iteration   1: 1.969 s/op
>   Iteration   2: 1.963 s/op
>   Iteration   3: 2.050 s/op
>   Iteration   4: 2.019 s/op
>   Iteration   5: 1.934 s/op
>   Iteration   6: 1.953 s/op
>   Iteration   7: 1.961 s/op
>   Iteration   8: 1.972 s/op
>   Iteration   9: 1.957 s/op
>   Iteration  10: 1.956 s/op
>   Iteration  11: 1.975 s/op
>   Iteration  12: 1.950 s/op
>   Iteration  13: 1.965 s/op
>   Iteration  14: 1.961 s/op
>   Iteration  15: 1.950 s/op
>   Iteration  16: 1.956 s/op
>   Iteration  17: 1.975 s/op
>   Iteration  18: 1.966 s/op
>   Iteration  19: 1.959 s/op
>   Iteration  20: 1.965 s/op
>
> Result "insertionSort":
>     1.968 ±(99.9%) 0.022 s/op [Average]   (min, avg, max) = (1.934, 1.968, 2.050), stdev = 0.025   CI (99.9%): [1.946, 1.990] (assumes normal distribution)
>
> ## Run complete. Total time: 00:09:55
>
> Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
>   MyBenchmark.heapSort       avgt   20  12.692 ± 0.282   s/op
>   MyBenchmark.insertionSort  avgt   20   2.024 ± 0.020   s/op

**Edit**: Since I've posted the question i added the @setup to set-up the array before the benchmark, so the array creation operations won't be a factor. I ran the benchmark again and the results for the insertion sort were pretty much the same. Heap sort benchmark got faster by 3 sec on avg. I've only posted the updated summary of the results.

Comment: Despite your comment, this is a duplicate; because in order to benchmark Java - which you are doing - you first need to learn _how_. Because of lack of warmup of the JVM and iterations, all you are really timing is the classloader and the JIT. When you have written some benchmarks in JMH, come back with another question.

Comment: Maybe i don't know how to benchmark java. This isn't the point. The point is levels of complexity and how somehow I violate the theoretical complexity of heap sort.

Comment: You don't violate any complexity, you're just not timing what you think you're timing. I'm sorry, but if you want meaningful benchmarks in Java you're going to have to learn how to write them.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have used JMH benchmark for testing the code. Please, remove duplicate.

Comment: Break leaves only the outer for-loop. Both impl. are correct. I've tested them.

Comment: MaxG, have you tried running your benchmark for different array sizes? Does the trend stay for arrays 10 times as big?

Comment: @Slanec I used the canonical definition of [insertion sort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/insertion_sort_algorithm.htm). Also, you can see that It's different from [Bubble sort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm). They both are of O(n^2) time complexity. Analyzing your suggestion (it's interesting): you find the insertion point in logn time, but the shifting is of linear complexity. If i'm not mistaken, in theory it should take longer because you run on n elements nlogn operations. It's amazing that it runs faster.

Comment: @CptBartender I currently am running a benchmark on 1M array size, but its gonna take a while :)

Comment: @MaxG Yes, sorry, it _is_ an insert sort, I got deceived by my own debugging. Still, it is true that both the version that first finds the correct index and then shifts all numbers; and the one with binary search instead, are faster (the binary one by a lot). The difference is that both comparing and swapping elements takes time, and the binary version does less of comparing. The linear variant, I presume, is faster because of caching / better branch prediction or something. Not sure. I'll check your heapsort later on.

Comment: Most likely the heap sort is taking so much time because you implemented it wrong. Your `sort` method calls `maxHeapify` `size` times, and each call there does `size/2` iterations. So what you've implemented is an O(n^2) sorting algorithm. You should only have to call `maxHeapify` once.

Comment: @JimMischel This should be an answer instead of a comment. It's the correct observation and fixing that (While also fixing the balancing afterwards as currently it only swaps a parent with his child once - some elements might need to bubble down further, though.) makes the job done.

Comment: @Slanec: Thanks. I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your heap sort is implemented incorrectly. The code you posted appears to be doing a selection sort. That is, for each item it calls `maxHeapify`, takes the first item in the heap, puts it at the end, and decreases the count. So `maxHeapify` is called `size` times, each time with a decreasing size. The number of iterations of the inner loop in `maxHeapify` ends up being something like `(n^2)/4`.

You've implemented a glorified selection sort with complexity O(n^2).

The trick to doing an in-place heap sort is to first build the heap--once--and then rearrange it to be sorted. You call `maxHeapify` once:

```
maxHeapify(size, arr);
```

When that's done, you have a valid max heap, with the largest item at `arr[0]`, etc. That takes O(n) time.

What you want is an array in ascending order. To do that, you build a loop that copies the largest item from the heap (i.e. `arr[0]`) and saves it temporarily. Then, take the last item in the heap, reduce the count by one, and then re-insert that item at the top, sifting it down as required. Finally, place the previous largest item at the position that was previously occupied by the last item. When count gets to 0, you have a sorted array:

```
int count = size;
while (count > 0)
{
    int save = arr[0];      // save the largest item
    arr[0] = arr[count-1];  // move last item to top
    arr[count-1] = save;    // and place the largest item
    count = count - 1;      // reduce the count
    SiftDown(0);            // sift item into place
}
```

All you're doing is successively calling `removeMax` on the heap, and storing the result back into the array in the position that was vacated.

`SiftDown` is the same method you use when inserting an item into a heap.

See my blog post, [A Simple Heap of Integers](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/30/a-simple-heap-of-integers/), for a complete example of building a heap using the O(n) heapify method. It's in C#, but I think simple enough that if you understand Java you can understand it. I don't show how to do the sort part, but with that code and the few lines above, you should do fine.

Comment: @MaxG: See the corrected code. As it was before, it could have caused an error.